# Multi Language not working in Sitecore headless

Tags: jss, graphql, nextjs

We are using Sitecore 10.2 as headless (JSS) and nextjs for the front end.

When we try to call JSS API it is working with multiple languages.

```
https://{Sitecore}/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss/?item={ItemID}&sc_apikey={apiKey}&sc_lang={langcode}
```

But from the front when we try to call, it is working only for EN, not working for other languages. Gives 404 when I try to access for a different language.
I guess we are missing something from the front end.
Please let me know if we are missing something.

Answer (score 4):

You would also need to configure the language on the frontend in the `next.config.js` file:

```
i18n: {
  locales: ['en', 'da-DK'],
},
```

Here is the official documentation: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/190/sitecore-headless-development/internationalization-in-the-jss-sample-app-for-next-js.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to export it as static files with `next export` it won't work. Here is the docs with limitations: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/201/sitecore-headless-development/walkthrough--exporting-a-jss-next-js-app-to-static-html-files-with-next-export.html

Comment: This is a link only answer, please update your answer with additional details